# Ways to produce atmosperic aphrodisiacs

Tags: planets, chemistry, population, biochemistry

I am a big player of Stellaris and some of the planets have the modifier **Atmospheric Aphrodisiac** so I was wondering, how could we achieve a planet wide production of aphrodisiacs.

The phenomenon should be felt everywhere livable on the planet (the part between the eternal shadow and the burning sunlight for a tidal locked planet for example)

The Aphrodisiac must be one for a spacefaring species, not necessarily for the fauna evolving on the planet. I was thinking of a human-like specie that was bulding a colony on this planet. These colonists must at least feel *horny* with the help of the same kind of chemicals that works on us.

Every process having the expected results is welcome, be creative!

Comment: Question s where every answer is  possibly equally valid are often closed ass primarily opinion  based. How could  anyone  decide  between  space algae and anti-human bioweapon, for example?  Also, what's so special about   humans  in this universe? Are there other races? And so on...

Comment: @Molot Humans and Earth-born animals are the only species that we could possibly know about the aphrodisiac that could work on them

Comment: The obvious problem with constant exposure to some drug is that people become accustomed to that or other side effects. Btw isn't the question exactly the same as: "How can anything more complex than simple hydrocarbons be found in the atmosphere of a planet?" which of course has rather obvious answers. So I'm asking you: What part of the concept do you struggle with? Do you lack knowledge about what would work as an aphrodisiac, about plants (for example the concept of pollen) or something else? What is the hurdle you do can't climb? Help can be provided best if the problem is identified

Comment: @Raditz_35  Actually I know we can have some plants used as aphrodisiacs, as ginger. But I don't actually know how the chemicals works or the other ways of producing thoses kind of chemicals. I know what pollens are but I didn't knew there were some of them acting as aphrodisiacs
So the lack of overall knowledge about aphrodisiacs may really be my struggle here...

Comment: @Calaom So you want to know what specific chemical would work and then how to synthesize it? I think this might be more on topic elsewhere. Also just because things are used as aphrodisiacs doesn't mean they actually work. Quacks have been selling variations of those things for thousands of years now and most if not all of them don't work

Comment: @Raditz_35 So that's the point that Tim B arose in his answer, that we don't actually have a conclusive answer to the questions about pheromons and also aphrodisiacs. Where do you think this question would have better fitted?

Comment: If you want to know "What substance is an aphrodisiac?" - biology. If you want to know "How can one synthesize substance x?" and you are not looking for the answer "genetically modify some organism" - chemistry. Long term exposure to a specific aphrodisiac - I don't know, maybe biology also. If you want to know how one can realistically put any substance (or one specific one that you have to name then) into the atmosphere of a planet, well, this is the right place. But again, aren't the answers obvious? You should at least state in that case why the obvious wouldn't work for you

Comment: PS: With that being said, the obvious questions with obvious answers tend to get a lot of attention because basically anyone can provide an answer. You might be so lucky, but it could help if you could clarify what you are actually asking

Comment: "Every process having the expected results is welcome, be creative!" -- So, you're saying that you have no constraints on what determines the "best" answer, or that there's so many possible answers you don't care which you use? That makes this either _primarily opinion-based_ or _too broad_.

Comment: @Frostfyre Raditz_35 Seems that you're right, my question is way too broad, I should at least look for some more answers by myself before asking this here. I put the Tim answer as right because it fits well the purpose even if too broad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Followers of some of my other answers will note that I continue to stress that I'm not an organic chemist, but that doesn't mean that I don't occasionally have an answer for a question such as this one. Today, we're going to explore [Musk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musk).

The question of aphrodisiacs and pheromones has yet to be conclusively answered by modern science, however for the purposes of this question we can be reminded that the original form of musk was harvested from a gland out of a musk deer (from Tibet if I'm not mistaken) by perfumers until the poor creatures were driven to the edge of extinction. The reason for this is that in VERY low concentrations, musk seems to have a very appealing aroma.

It was also (allegedly) how musk deer sought mates. It is (again, allegedly) a pheromone. It's also a very complex CHO compound. In this case, I'm going to avoid using the term carbohydrate as the semantic use to which the word is put would not do the compound justice. Suffice it to say, that for an organic compound, it's not that hard to synthesise which is what ultimately saved the deer musk as perfumers mastered the creation of 'white musk', a synthetic form of the compound.

So, no; I'm not going to clone the daylights out of these poor creatures and kill them en masse to harvest enough musk pods to saturate an atmosphere. Besides it being inhumane, it's impractical. You'd need the land mass of around 100 worlds working full time to raise musk deer to saturate the atmosphere of a single planet. But fear not, there's another solution; plants.

Take for instance the [Tropical Jewel Hibiscus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelmoschus_moschatus), also known by several other names of course, and the [Wild Celery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angelica_archangelica). Both are known for producing chemical aromas quite similar to musk. So; what we do is we engage in a little horticulture and produce a plant that produces EXACTLY deer musk (after all it's a CHO compound so it's possible) in large quantities, which it releases as a bouquet into the atmosphere. Then we just plant *massive* amounts of this on every land surface of the planet we can find.

Et Voila! A planet who's every surface is covered by aphrodisiac releasing plant life.

This has several advantages over more synthetic techniques. First of all, the plants grow in habitable regions, as per the question. No point having plants where humans can't be. Also, they're always releasing, so no concerns about dissipation. The release mechanism takes no energy to run; it's effectively solar powered (photosynthesis) which is already optimised to produce O2 (which our humans need anyway) and CHO compounds; they just produce an extra one which they release. For Free. Finally, the compound is released close to the ground, again where the humans are. No need to saturate the entire atmosphere and face dissipation concerns up high where the compound won't be consumed anyway.

All in all, a relatively cheap, low energy solution that makes for a great holiday destination.

Answer (score 3):

## The answer is specific to each alien's biochemistry

There are too many ways for this to happen, and each way is based on the biochemistry of whatever aliens are there.

First off, lets say that it is unlikley that the atmosphere of a planet will be an aphrodisiac to the creatures that evolved there. But, having played *Stellaris*, that isn't how this works; the aphrodisiac works on alien settlers colonizing that world.

So there are a few possibilities for how this could happen.

- There is a compound freely floating in the air that is an aphrodisiac. This is highly unlikely, to say the least. Human aphrodisiacs are complex  organics like [crocin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crocin) and [bremelanotide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremelanotide).
- There is a compound freely floating in the air that, when ingested into the alien's body, undergoes or catalyzes a chemical reaction that results in the production of an aphrodisiac. And example of this might be something interacts with [phenethylamine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenethylamine) present in human bodies to create [amphetamines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphetamine). Don't ask me how that would work; I tried to google how to make amphetamines at work until I realized that I was probably on an FBI watchlist and/or about to get fired.

Comment: Nice answer, I like the second idea that the atmosphere contains only the compound making the settler synthetize the aphrodisiav by himself. So now I just have to find a formula to produce amphetamines, bonus if I don't have any problems with the police! ^^'
Please don't make research that are that risky, there's no need to get the answer that far!